# How can I make this menu effect with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, menu

I've seen this menu effect on many sites but I don't know if there were a plugin/tutorial to make some thing like this ?
see this example:
http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/TheProfessional/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lava Lamp](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lavalamp2) is your answer.

However, you can find some other cool jquery animated menu plugin here: [36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/)

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the source for the example you gave shows it is using [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/).

The good thing about the web is everything is open. Find something you like (you've got that already), then look at the source and figure out how they are doing it. Tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [LavaLamp](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lavalamp2) JQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

First you absolutely or relatively position the menu div.

There are two childs to the menu div: one is a div of the text items (let's call it Text), and the other is a div of the animated chasing element (let's call it Chaser).

Set the Chaser to be absolutely positioned and the Text to be relatively positioned.

Set the Text to have a higher z-index than the chaser.

For each text element, use jquery to bind a hover callback to it.

That hover callback says "find the offset of the element that is being hovered over; tell Chaser to animate its position to match that offset".